# How to find passing rate in WindowsForm c# in a dataGridView?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm new to C# so please excuse my dumb question.

So. I've got a program that prompts the user to input their name and grade achieved. So far I can find the average grade, and the highest grade outof the given grades in a dataGridView.

Here's the average and max code:

```
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txt_name.Text, txt_grade.Text);

    private void btn_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] columnData = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows
                            where row.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString()!= string.Empty
                            select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue)).ToArray();


        lbl_average.Text = "Average grade is: " + columnData.Average().ToString();
        lbl_highest.Text = "Highest grade is: " + columnData.Max().ToString();
    }
```

I now need to get the pass rate. For example the pass rate is 50 marks. If 2 out of 5 students score 50 or higher, the pass rate should be 40% and it should be displayed on my lbl_passrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the columns are each class and the rows are each student based on how you're doing the Average and Max. If so then you'll need some internal variable to hold the passing threshold, 50 marks in your example. So then you use Linq to easily get what you're after. You'll probably need to check for divid by zero errors but this is the gist of it:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txt_name.Text, txt_grade.Text);

private void btn_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int passingMarks = 50;

    int[] columnData = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows
                        where row.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString()!= string.Empty
                        select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue)).ToArray();


    lbl_average.Text = "Average grade is: " + columnData.Average().ToString();
    lbl_highest.Text = "Highest grade is: " + columnData.Max().ToString();
    var passingStudents = columnData.AsQueryable().Where(g=>g >= passingMarks).Count();
    var passingRate = ((double)passingStudents / columnData.Length) * 100;

    lbl_passrate.Text = String.Format("Pass Rate = {0}%", passingRate);
}
```

Comment: This displays a 0 no matter what, what can I do to solve this?

Comment: @SaraMilikj You'll need to cast to floating-point. It can be `passingStudents`, for example, and the rest of the expression will cast implicitly. Then multiply by 100 to get the percentage. You may have to do some additional formatting, too.

Comment: @SaraMilikj I just updated the answer, now it should cast it to a double and multiply by 100 for you.

Comment: @chris-crush-code The cast has to occur before the division or you're still just doing integer division.